# SlowCheetah not transforming during MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xslt, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, slowcheetah

I've implemented SlowCheetah in a web project. I'm running NuGet v2.7, but still using Enable Package Restore. I run a build workflow in AntHillPro that first runs NuGet Package Restore then MSBuild on the solution. The Package Restore steps indicates it is successfully reinstalling SLowCheetah, but the MSBuild step shows no execution of the transform process for config files other than web.config. I tried switching to the v2.7 NuGet Command Line Restore but that changed nothing. I'm back with Enable Package Restore but I have no idea where to go from here and how to debug this problem. I'd swear it was working correctly a couple of weeks ago. Not sure if I have a SlowCheetah problem or a NuGet problem. How do I debug this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Web projects only transform on publish or package, not on build. There is a long standing feature request for me to get it working for web, but I have not yet gotten there.

Comment: Off-topic: we also use AnthillPro - are you able to get the packages you are retrieving from NuGet to be reported in AHP as dependencies of your build life, or are these 'invisible' in the dependency graph?

Comment: nuGet packages don't show up as dependencies. We could probably script something to figure this out but we have bigger fish to fry right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that during a merge, in my csproj file, the PropertyGroup (labelled SlowCheetah) went down the Import element.

It should be like this

```
<PropertyGroup Label="SlowCheetah">
  <SlowCheetahToolsPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.10.3\tools\))</SlowCheetahToolsPath>
  <SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet Condition=" '$(SC_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='' ">true</SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet>
  <SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)'=='' ">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\SlowCheetah\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets ))</SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath>
  <SlowCheetahTargets Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='true' and Exists('$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)') ">$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)</SlowCheetahTargets>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then

```
<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171464.aspx#Anchor_1) is why the order of elements is important in a build file. Hope it helps

Comment: I THINK this has cleared up for us. I haven't seen any instances since we moved off VS2010 to VS2012+. Maybe the Project file management got better? I have no way at this point to reproduce the problem since the project was upgraded to VS2012 and the condition you documented doesn't exist in the Project file. I'll mark this as the answer assuming you're right and keep it in mind if it happens again. :-)